# Unable to upload image from an ImageView to FireBase Storage in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

In my application I have an ImageView, I want to save the image associated with that imageView to Firebase Storage. This is what i have done:

```
imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imageview.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageview.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();


StorageReference mStorage;
//CURRENT_USER,CCC,CAPITAL,TYPE are strings.
mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(CCC).child(Case+"/"+CAPITAL+"_"+TYPE.replaceAll(" ","_")+"_front.jpg");

mStorage.putBytes(data).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        //return null;
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                        return mStorage.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                            Log.d("save_document",downloadUri.toString());                                
                        } else {
                            Log.d("save_document","failed to upload image");
                        }
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d("save_document","Exception while uploading the image"+e.toString());
                }
            });
```

The image is never uploaded in Firebase storage, and also the log statements are never executed, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Add `addOnFailureListener()` and check what exception you get

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I added onfailure listener, it didn't go into that also

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference();
                storageReference.child("profileImageUrl").child(userID).putFile(resultUri)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                mCustomerDatabase1.child("profileImageUrl").setValue(url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Successfully Uploaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
                                        else{

                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not Successfully Uploaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not Successfully Uploaded",LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This is a piece of code from a project of mine. I hope it helps.

```
private static final int Gallery_Pick_Fin = 1;
private Uri ImageUriFin;
ImageView addFinImg;
private String downloadUrlFin;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        addFinImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.add_cmnt_img);

        addFinImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        openGalleryFin();
                    }
                });

        postRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Posting... \n Please Wait.. :)");
                progressDialog.show();
                    final StorageReference filePath = postFinPicsRef.child("postFinPics").child(ImageUriFin.getLastPathSegment() + user.getUid());
                    filePath.putFile(ImageUriFin).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                downloadUrlFin = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                dbRefUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid());

                                dbRefUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                        HashMap<String, Object> userPosts = new HashMap<>();
                                        userPosts.put("FinPic", downloadUrlFin);


                                        dbRefPost.child(user.getUid()).child("" + aa).updateChildren(userPosts);
                                        dbRefPostAll.child("Veg").child("" + aa).updateChildren(userPosts);
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostTabActivity.class));
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });

            }
        });


    }


private void openGalleryFin() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,Gallery_Pick_Fin);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == Gallery_Pick_Fin && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null){
        ImageUriFin = data.getData();
        addFinImg.setImageURI(ImageUriFin);
    }
}
```